# Dynamically resizing images using AWS S3/Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So I have a web app that stores images in a single bucket, following this principle (folder with the name of the user id, pictures with the name of user id + some random characters in the respected user id folder).

Now I already implemented a python script that takes uploaded image from a single bucket (root folder, or any folder I specify) and outputs it to another bucket/folder I specify. I'm just wondering if it's possible to do this in real time with my situation (I don't even need to export the resized pics to another bucket, they can stay in the same folder the original was uploaded to). This is part of the script I'm using right now. Any help appreciated.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
     
def resize_image(image_path, resized_path):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        image.thumbnail((128, 128))
        image.save(resized_path)
     
def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key'] 
        download_path = '/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
        upload_path = '/resized-{}'.format(key)
        
        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        resize_image(download_path, upload_path)
        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, '{}-resized'.format(bucket), key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! It looks like you grabbed the sample code from the Lambda documentation: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

You can configure an **Amazon S3 Event** to trigger the AWS Lambda function whenever a new object is added to the S3 bucket. In fact, that is how the tutorial operates. This is effectively "real-time" because it triggers as soon as an object is uploaded. (Just configure the prefixes so it doesn't trigger an infinite loop.)

An alternative to resizing the images yourself is to use a service that can resize on-the-fly, such as:

- [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)
- [Imgix](http://imgix.com/)